# Java Eclipse Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, javah

I need to generate header file using java in `Jni` sub-folder of my project using external tools in eclipse IDE. When I select my class in the project, I get this error:

> Cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found

The External Tool have this parameters:

```
Location: C:\MyProgram\Java\jdk-8u20\bin\javah.exe
Working dir: ${project_loc}/bin/classes
Arguments:   -verbose -classpath C:\MyProgram\Java\android-sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar; -d  ${project_loc}/jni  -jni ${java_type_name}
```

I think I need to add android.support.v7 but don't know how.
I tried adding `${workspace_loc}\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar;` to Arguments:

```
-verbose -classpath C:\MyProgram\Java\android-sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar;${workspace_loc}\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar;  -d  ${project_loc}/jni  -jni ${java_type_name}
```

But it generated this error:

> Not a valid class name: ....\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar;

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Change the content of working dir parameter to:

${project_loc}/src

solve the problem.